# How to store typed combobox inputs into the combobox list, for the current session only?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Combobox with content I added in the "String Collection Editor" from the ComboBox properties tab. That content is the default selection for the current userform session. If someone types into the combobox I would like the input to stay in the list for the remainder if the current userform session. Is there a way to achieve this?

Any help would be great.
Thank You

Comment: I don't get your question. You have a combobox, you want to type text in it and add the inputted text to the ComboBox.Items collection, then make that item selected. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I made a form in VB Excel and it automatically added it to the list. But now that I'm switching it to .NET its not adding to the list. I'm very new to VB.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Combobox.Items.Add(ComboBox.Text)` ? You can place that in the `KeyPress` event (handling the enter key) of the combobox. Then Call `Combobox.SelectedIndex = Combobox.Items.Count - 1` to select the newly added item.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much @preciousbetine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to add the item to the Items Collection of the `Combobox` when the enter key is pressed. Then make the newly added item the currently displayed one.
The below code should work if that is what you are trying to do.

I also assume that the name of the combobox is `Combobox1`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Combobox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.KeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(Combobox1.Text)
      ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually have it setup to Add when a button is clicked. It worked perfectly, thanks for teaching me something new!